# Terminology: Max. and min. vs. highest and lowest

Tags: terminology, graphs

In a line graph, there is a highest point and a lowest point.

But what are these called? max and min or highest and lowest?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Min (minimum) and max (maximum) are the correct terminology.

Comment: What about this then: Mean or Average? :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually they are referred to as peaks and troughs. Although some types of graphs have special wording since the troughs mean something. For example: in a parabola both the peaks and troughs are referred to as its vertex.

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/274560/the-term-for-the-negative-equivalent-of-a-peak-point-on-a-graph